# Should I write my name with an already gained bachelor title in another bachelor thesis?

Tags: thesis, degree, bachelor

I am writing my second bachelor thesis for a completely different degree and don't know if I should put my name with my already gained title(B.Sc) onto the title page. I live in a country where even bachelor titles are added to the name most of the time, but am not sure if I should/could do that for my  other bachelor thesis. The thesis is written in english, if that's important.

Comment: I personally wouldn't (although I think I was formally required to put the M.Sc. on the PhD. thesis, but then again, the PhD. title-page kind of has a special status in Germany). In my opinion, a thesis should stand on its own and not be related to any previous merits. But you should check other thesis in your country, specifically master theses, where there definitely is a preexisting title, to see how they do it.

Comment: @mlk Good the idea with master theses, they all have the bachelor title in them. Austria just loves their titles...

Comment: I don't think anyone can answer this as it's entirely dependent on the thesis regulations of the institution where you are studying. These regulations will usually define what should be on the title page, fonts, margins and how any academic titles should appear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The good news is that it doesn't matter. Very few people will read the thesis. If it is normative in your country to add B.Sc after a name, then you have the right to add it wherever you choose. This is not normative in the US or UK, where I have worked. However, there's no requirement that all titles be used, even in formal contexts. In sum: you can choose.